# Print unique values and corresponding IP in linux log file

Tags: linux

I have a log file in that files having a couple of records.
In that log file second, the column contains IP address and the third column contains the port.
I want to know the unique port values with the corresponding IP from the second column

Comment: any one help me

Comment: What problem are you having? Make a [mcve].